# JPA & HQL: No data type for node error

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, entity, hql

I'm having difficulty mapping a custom query.

In my My Spring Data Rest repo:

```
@RestResource(rel = "by-userperson-id")
@Query(value = "select user from User where userId in(select u.user.userId from Userperson u where u.personId = ?1)")
User findByUserpersonId(@Param("id") Integer id);
```

My entity classes like so.

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter @Setter
public class User implements Serializable {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private Integer userId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Userperson> userPersons;
```

}

Userperson:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userperson")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Userperson implements Serializable {

@Getter
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "USERPERSON_ID")
private Integer userPersonId;

@Getter @Setter
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
private int personId;

@Getter @Setter
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private User user;
```

}

But I keep getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.dfd.wash.domain.user.User com.dfd.wash.domain.user.UserRepo.findByUserpersonId(java.lang.Integer)!
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:144)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:212)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
... 83 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
IdentNode: 'user' {originalText=user}

at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:160)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:920)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:688)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:673)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:309)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:257)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
... 96 more
```

I assume it has something to do with casing in my HQL statement in the @Query annotation, i.e. entity properties vs. database columns, But I can't seem to nail the correct statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this will work `"select u from User u where u.userId in(select upr.user.userId from Userperson upr where upr.personId = ?1)"` just minor corrections in aliases

Comment: And if you use positional parameter you can remove the @Param annotation

Comment: Solved it! Thanks a bunch! Made my day @john. And thanks for the tip Z